# jQuery click svg

Tags: jquery, svg

Is there any way to select an svg with jQuery?. I do not want to manipulate anything. Just click, as any img.

(I know they are some external libraries to manipulate svg. But what I am asking here is if it is possible just click with jQuery and nothing else)

Please check your answer here:http://jsfiddle.net/NUCwg/

HTML:

```
<div id="content" > 
    <object data="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/HTML5_Badge.svg" 
        type="image/svg+xml" id="svg"> 
        <img src="grafic.png" alt="BG"> 
    </object> 
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
    $("#content").click(function() {
        $("#content").fadeOut("normal");
    });
})
```

Comment: not related to your issue, but you should end your img tag.

Comment: @smerny not unless you are not validating against XHTML.

Comment: @smerny img is a self closing tag, no need to close it: <img src="..." alt="..."> is W3C valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you cannot bind event to object/svg from cross domain, you could trick it using this kind of hack {using an overlay}:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NUCwg/9/)

```
$(function () {
    var $content = $('#content'),
        $overlay = $('<div/>').width($content.width()).height($content.height()).css({
            position: 'absolute',
            left: $content.offset().left,
            top: $content.offset().top
        }).appendTo('body').click(function () {
            $content.add(this).fadeOut("normal");
        });
})
```

Comment: If you want a raster fallback, this is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/NUCwg/6/

I think that your solution didn't work because jQuery can't fade `object` or `embed` elements (see http://jsfiddle.net/9CVFd/1/). The only downside of my solution is that it lacks a raster fallback.